# PHP check if multiple value

Tags: attributes

I currently use the following code to check if the attribute got a specific value.

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Cisco"): ?>
```

But now I need to add another value that it needs to check.

Is this the correct way to check this?

```
 <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Cisco" && $_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Dell"): ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you pasted:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Cisco" && $_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Dell"): ?>
```

Means:

**If the brand name is Cisco AND Dell.**

That's very unlikely in my opinion.

If you want to know:

**If the brand name is Cisco OR Dell.**

You can do:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Cisco" || $_product->getAttributeText('brand_name') == "Dell"): ?>
```

Or another way of doing it is:

```
<?php if (in_array($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name'),array("Cisco","Dell")): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

if(in_array($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name'), array('Cisco','Dell','Sony'))) {

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Mage::hepler('catalog/product')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getBrandName(), 'brand_name')
```

But as you are using asking this attribute multiple times. So You can use

```
$_product->getBrandName()
```

So that your code works fast.

Also you can do it by using array check

```
in_array($_product->getAttributeText('brand_name'), array('A','B','C'));
```

Where **A,B,C** is the value of checking